# Подскажите как вы реализуете архитектуру в своем коде?

Tags: c++

Я иногда пишу модули для своего кода, для меня очень важно сделать это проще. Покажу вам как я это делаю, кажется это выглядит очень плохо.
Возможно я делаю все правильно, но вероятно нет.

Вариант для нескольких типов

```
template <typename T1>
void sample1(T1& type)
{
    switch (type)
    {

        case 0: // alfa
            // код alfa
            break;

        case 2: // beta
            // код beta
            break;

        case 3: // gamma
            // код gamma
            break;

        case 4: // delta
            // код delta
            break;

        default:
            // варианта типа нету
            break;
    }

}
```

Вариант только для двух типов

```
template <typename T1>
void sample2(T1& type)
{
    if (type == 0)
    {
        // код zero 
    }
    else
    {
        // код first
    }
}
```

Вызываем функции в зависимости какой тип нужен

```
int alfa = 0,
    beta = 1,
    gamma = 2,
    delta = 3;

int zero = 0,
    first = 1;

int main()
{
    // вариант 1
    sample1(delta); // тут мне понадобился код delta

    // вариант 2
    sample2(zero); // здесь мне нужен код zero

    return 0;
}
```

Покажите как делаете это вы.

Comment: Какое отношение имеет архитектура к представленным кускам кода со свичом?

Comment: @VTT Архитектура это искусство проектировать и строить объекты, switch здесь просто код.

Comment: Архитектура строится под конкретные задачи и конкретное назначение части программы. Рассуждать на чем-то абстрактом не получится, как минимум не понятная связь между кусками кода и почему они лежат в одной функции? Почему нельзя сделать разные методы в отдельном классе? Зачем там нужен template вместо `void sample(int option)`? Эти вопросы исходят из задачи.

Comment: думаю тебе понравится вместо этого использовать полиморфизм классов с помощью наследования...

Comment: Использовать классы вместо функций?

Comment: @AlexKrass можно использовать `void sample(int option)` это верно, но разве это что то изменит?

Comment: Если вопрос был про шаблоны, то я их использую что бы типы не повторять.
Тип указан в параметрах шаблона, это удобней.

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать разные метода. 
Можно сделать, но лучше все поместить в одну функцию, так будет меньше кода и не нужно лишний раз делать наследования.
Более того, я не сторонник создания лишних классов, если можно сделать функцию вместо класса, надо делать функцию.

Comment: У вас в условии не сравнение, а присваивание. Сравнение это `==`.

Comment: @trollingchar исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Архитектура и разработка программного обеспечения в стиле ООП накладывает определенные условия. В частности, у вас реальный мир разделяется на объекты реального мира, у которых есть свойства и есть поведение. На основе этого в программу закладываются классы, которые их описывают.

Согласно хорошему проектированию, каждая часть программы должна нести одну конкретную функцию. К примеру, в следующем коде бухгалтер высчитывает налоги согласно зарплаты работника.

```
class Employee {
private:
    string _name;
    int _salary;
    int _workBand;
public:
    Employee(string name, int salary, int workExperience) {
        _name = name;
        _salary = salary;
        _workBand = workExperience;
    }

    void SetName(string name) { _name = name; }
    string GetName() { return _name; }

    void SetSalary(int salary) { _salary = salary; }
    int GetSalary() { return _salary; }

    void SetBand(int workBand) { _workBand = workBand; }
    int GetBand() { return _workBand; }
};

class Accountant {
public:
    int GetTaxes(Employee *emp) {
        switch (emp->GetBand())
        {
        case 1:
            return emp->GetSalary() * 0.2;
            break;
        case 2:
            return emp->GetSalary() * 0.1;
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Функция GetTaxes несет конкретную цель и считает в зависимости от уровня работника в компании. Если вы пытаетесь запихнуть в функцию несколько несвязанных действий, то с точки зрения проектирования это ошибка.

```
class Accountant{
public:
    int GetCalc(Employee *emp, int type) {
        switch (type)
        {
        case 1: // Считаем налоги
            return emp->GetSalary() * 0.2;
            break;
        case 2: // Считаем премию
            return emp->GetSalary() * 3 * 0.2;
            break;
        case 3: // Считаем одобренный кредит в банке
            return emp->GetSalary() * (10 + emp->GetBand() * 10);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Если когда-нибудь ваш бухгалтер перестанет считать одобренный кредит (да и с чего бы ему это делать?), то удаление части кода приведет к проблемам. Во-первых, вам придется удалить все вхождения `type=3` из всего кода. А во-вторых, если вы пропустите код, то ошибку вы получите уже только в время выполнения. В большом проекте это крайне критично и многие рекомендации даются за счет опыта набивания шишек. Нормальный класс будет выглядеть так.

```
class Accountant{
public:
    int GetTaxes(Employee *emp) {
        switch (emp->GetBand())
        {
        case 1:
            return emp->GetSalary() * 0.2;
            break;
        case 2:
            return emp->GetSalary() * 0.1;
            break;
        }
    }

    int GetBounty(Employee *emp) {
        emp->GetSalary() * 3 * 0.2;
    }
};

class Bank {
public:
    int GetMaxCredit(Employee *emp) {
        return emp->GetSalary() * (10 + emp->GetBand() * 10);
    }
};
```

Да, тут даже код для расчета кредита выделен в отдельный класс. Зато теперь, при удалении функциональности или ее изменение, мне не придется заглядывать в каждый угол программы и ожидать ошибку из-за своей невнимательности.

Если вы хотите добавить новую функциональность, вы добавляете новые классы и изолированные функции. Это излишество, которое позволяет избежать многих проблем, которые появляются не сразу в вашей программе. А исправлять ошибки в крупном проекте на поздних этапах очень долго и накладно, а иногда и невозможно. Поэтому в крупных проектах почти всегда функциональность разносится по классам и порой классы создаются даже ради одной единственной функции. Или делают большие цепочки наследований с полиморфизмом.

Опять же, классы и связь между ними строится исходя из предметной области и полностью его повторяет. Поэтому сложно говорить о проектировании без самой задачи проектирования. А различных вариантов крайне много и есть целые книги по правильному проектированию. Описать все нюансы в одном ответе не представляется возможным.

Но если вы пихаете в switch разную не связанную функциональность, это однозначно ошибка. Просто она может проявиться в фатальном виде или может вообще не проявиться, в зависимости от ситуации.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, разве правильно использовать так много классов, и как тогда вы называете свои файлы в проекте?
Обычно файлы называются по названию класса.

Comment: А почему вы используете тире перед названием переменных?
   `int _salary;`
`_workBand` я заметил что много людей так пишут, но не могу понять почему, обычно так пишут в системных файлах языка.

Comment: @user файлы так и называются по имени класса, иногда файлы организуются в подпапки для удобства. Иметь много классов не является проблемой и хорошо отражает содержание. Много где можно встретить, что нижний знак подчеркивания обычно означает приватную переменную, а двойное подчеркивание системные переменные. На самом деле я просто редко беру в руки C++ и забыл как делать присваивание через `this`: `this->name = name;`, поэтому выкрутился так, чтобы не гуглить.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно решать как лучше хранить указатели на функции(код). Для примера можно написать такой класс_хранилище(хотя можно все хранить и в стандартных контейнерах типа  std::map и др.):

```
class Storage {
    using Code = void(*)();
    std::vector<Code> fs;
public:
   //один из методов добавить указатели
    void
    add_code(std::initializer_list<Code> lst) 
    {

        fs.insert(fs.begin(), lst.begin(), lst.end());
    }
    //вызов соответствующей  функции
    void operator ()(const size_t n)
    {
        if (fs.empty()) return;
        const size_t sz = fs.size() - 1;
        if (n < sz)
            fs[n]();
        else {
            fs[sz]();
        }
    }
};
```

И наши коды сохраним в разных функциях:

```
void alfa() { cout << "a\n"; }
void beta() { cout << "b\n"; }
void gamma() { cout << "g\n"; }
void delta() { cout << "d\n"; }
void zero() { cout << "0\n"; }
void first() { cout << "first\n"; }
```

Тогда программу можно написать так:

```
Storage sample;
sample.add_code({ alfa, beta, gamma, delta, zero, first });
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   sample(i);
```

Comment: Хорошая реализация, особенно перебор через цикл.